# ip mask pattern calculation

Tags: ip, ip-address

I need to exclude an IP range from a tool. The tool offers the ability to add a mask pattern. Instructions: For instance, if you enter 144.133.0.0/16 all IPs from 144.133.0.0 - 144.133.255.255 will be selected.

I have no idea how to calculate the correct mask but I need to exclude the following range (inclusive): 144.133.255.0 - 144.133.255.63

Also, detail about *how* you got to the answer (would like to learn).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in each octet ranges from 0 to 255.
(0000 0000 to 1111 1111). Your IP address starts with 144 so it is a class B address. The default mask for class B is `255.255.0.0`.
The notation `144.133.0.0/16` is same as using the default mask `255.255.0.0`.
Hence there is only one subnet and the range is from `144.133.0.0` to `144.133.255.255`. The subnet mask `144.133.0.0/16` tells you the first 16 bits are in the mask.

A subnet mask of `255.255.255.192` will select hosts between HostMin:   `144.133.0.1` and `144.133.0.62`. The subnet mask of `255.255.255.192` is same as `144.133.0.0/26`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being extremely stupid... But I need to provide answer in terms of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Y

Comment: The first 26 bits are 1 for 255.255.255.192. Hence 144.133.0.0/26.